# Checking for diagonal for any size of Tic Tac Toe board with more than 3 players

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

So I am checking for the '' first and I notice that despite meeting certain requirements, it does not declare a winner. I do not think it is reading and setting a lineup when doing diagonals. I sort of based it on my row and col methods that work fine by the way.

So my question is how to go through any size of the board detecting a certain amount of player's icon and returning back that info of being a diagonal? the `userWinCondition` is also a player's choice of how many symbols are needed to be in a row to win.

```
public boolean checkLeftDiagonal(int row, int col,char[][] board, int player, int numberPlayers, int userWinCondition)
    {
//        System.out.println(userWinCondition);

        boolean leftWinner;

        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++)
            {
                leftWinner = true;

                for(int p = 0; p < userWinCondition; p++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if(!(board[i][(j-1) + p] == tokenList.get(player)))
                        {
                            leftWinner = false;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
                    {
                        leftWinner = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(leftWinner)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Checking the diagonal which starts from top-left and ends in bottom-right of a square should only require a single loop. Can you please explain what is the use of each of the 3 loops?

Comment: This is a homework question, it also lacks enough detail to be answered

Comment: Not really hw question it is a big term project that I have tried for a week solving it but could not. But the other part of the project has all been finished now. Had a month doing this project.

So what I was thinking of for the 2nd for loops was to go through the board through the columns. The third loop was to detect a certain amount of players' tokens to win. Either a set of 3 or 4 of a repeated player's symbol pattern in a row or in this case diagonally.

Comment: but yes the third loop I see it as a bit important thing as I want to loop around finding a win condition of the user input that is either a 3 or a 4  thus gets to the try and catch and the if the statement of catching a set of pattern that has that player symbol and if it catches that it breaks and gets to the other if statement returning the winner of the game.

Comment: Please show input and expected/actual output.